# Phase noise and clock jitter

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am running a wireless communication system like follows. I create a baseband signal in matlab and output it to a transmitter that performs upmixing. The receiver mixes down the signal again and I got back the baseband signal in matlab. So far this works fine, however, I observe that the clocks of both transceiver are neither synchron nor perfect. I got clock jitter that results in phase noise (rotation in the constellation). Somehow the clock jitter seams to be periodic. Is there any possibility to get rid of the phase error in software?

I have attached a matlab script to clarify my problem. Solving the problem of phase noise in this simulation should hopefully fix my problem. 
From the phase-difference I can successfully determine the constant carrier frequency offset (CFO), but I have no idea how to deal with the oscillations in the phase-difference.

```
f_s     = 40e6; % Sampling frequency
f_d     = 2e4;  % Frequency offset
f_mix   = 15e6; % Mixer frequency

clock_jitter=true;
if clock_jitter
     f_d = f_d + 2e3*sin(2 * pi * 1e5/f_s * t.');
end

% Plot the frequency offset
figure;
plot(t, f_d);
title('frequency offset');

% Generate random data
t = 1:1e3-1;
payload_tx      = randi([0, 3], [length(t), 1]);
signal_tx       = qammod(payload_tx, 4);
scatterplot(signal_tx);

%Mix up
signal_pb = signal_tx .* exp(1j * 2 * pi * f_mix ./ f_s * t.');

% Mix down
signal_rx = signal_pb .* exp(-1j * 2 * pi .* (f_mix+f_d) ./ f_s .* t.');
scatterplot(signal_rx);

% Correct the CFO
f_shift     = exp(1j * angle(signal_tx ./ signal_rx));
f_drift     = f_shift(2:end) ./ f_shift(1:end-1);
f_drift_m   = angle(sum(f_drift));
cfo         = f_drift_m .* f_s ./ (2 * pi);
disp(['Estimated CFO to ', num2str(cfo), 'Hz']);
signal_rx_cfo_cor = signal_rx .* exp(1j * f_drift_m * t.');
scatterplot(signal_rx_cfo_cor);

% Plot the phase difference of the received signal
figure;
plot(1:length(f_drift), unwrap(angle(f_drift)));
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Presumably the phase difference is not predictable in advance - otherwise you could easily subtract off the phase difference when you mix back down to baseband. If it's not predictable in advance, I guess you need to sample it periodically and use this information to predict what it will be during the next transmission cycle. Estimation theory deals with algorithms for accomplishing this task, but there's unlikely to be a one-size-fits-all solution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Dave. Unfortunately, I am not able to change anything at the transceivers itself. I can only adjust the modulation of the baseband scheme itself. Are you aware of any modulation that is kind of resistant to high phase noise?

Comment: Generically, any frequency-mixing process is vulnerable to phase noise. There are various ways that you can try to correct for the phase noise by modulating the Matlab carrier signal and examining the effect on the receiver signal. However, without knowing more about your setup and the signal you are trying to transmit, I can't recommend any particular way forward. Frankly, I think this is not really a Stack Overflow problem since it is not a coding issue. If you want to take it to Electronics Stack Exchange, I am also on that site and we can continue there.